# English SharePoint site with mix of Chines and English file names

Tags: language

I am trying to execute published Captivate simulations on SP. The file name is a mixture of English and Chinese characters (VF01 - 创建商业发票-SD.htm). It works correctly on my local PC. When I upload the file to SP, it will not execute. If I rename the file to all English characters (VF01 -ChineseTest-SD.htm), republish, and upload, it works fine on SP. Does the SP server need to have have a language pack installed to allow the file to correctly execute with a Chinese file name?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should probably require Chinese Language pack installed for identifying file names in Chinese language.

You can download them here - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3411